# Recreate single docker-compose container with new config

Tags: docker, docker-compose

If I make changes to my `docker-compose.yml` (say, change which host port a container port is exposed on), can I recreate that single container or do I need to restart the whole stack?

`docker-compose stop ; docker-compose up` will do the job but I want to avoid restarting the rest of the services.  I also want to avoid deleting volumes associated with the service that I'm restarting, so `docker-compose kill <service> ; docker-compose rm` is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run `docker-compose up` again. Everything that is impacted by your change (container, volume, network, etc.) is going to be recreated, the other containers will stay.

If you want to use newer images, run `docker-compose pull` beforehand.

Comment: I have `env_file: -myenv` in `compose.yml`, changes to that file are ignored by 'docker compose up'

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes changes to some env file are ignored. Then I do

```
docker stop mycontainer
docker compose up
```

this will restart single container plus dependent containers which is what you do. Avoiding restarting dependent containers is bad idea, because `mycontainer` will come up with different docker ip

having some kind of `reload` command would be nice